# Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path

Tags: boot, server, usb, windows

Im trying to boot ubuntu `14.10-server-i386` in a pendrive.

But im getting this error when boot from pendrive.

> Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path

What does it mean? How to overcome that?

Comment: check this question, http://askubuntu.com/questions/524875/booting-from-a-usb-on-a-pc-syslinux-boot-promt?rq=1

Answer (score 122, accepted):

After the error message, try hitting **Tab**, type in *live* and hit **Enter**. This should get you to the Ubuntu desktop from where you can use the Install icon to go forward with the installation.

Comment: It worked for me!

Comment: I had to type 'live'

Comment: Same problem with `ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64` and it worked too, thanks!

Comment: I just had this same problem with `ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64` on my HP Pavilion dv9000. Dropping to the boot prompt and booting to 'live' worked. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Bug un the installer?

Comment: Same problem with ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64 and it worked too, thanks!

Comment: Same problem with ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64 and it worked too, thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 as well

Comment: same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It works

Comment: Worked for my on Ubuntu 16.04 with `live-install` to skip straight to the installation. I noticed this installation is much slower than in previous versions i even thought it was frozen after selecting the language. By the way why is this error happening? I mean this is the installation of an LTS version it should go smooth

Comment: so here is the explanation "long version" http://askubuntu.com/a/746412/59618

Comment: same issue on 17.04..but keyboard is not working.. how to type anything

Answer (score 5):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1325801). It happens when you create a bootable USB stick with an older version of Ubuntu than the version being installed on the USB stick.

Although the answer selected by the person who asked the question works to get around the issue it does not fix it as you have to do it every time you boot the USB stick.

---

To fix the USB installation so you do not have to type **live** and hit **Enter** every time you want to use it to live boot:

In the boot: prompt after you hit the error above, type **live** and press **Enter**, to start the Live USB session.

Open a terminal (e.g. with Ctrl+Alt+t) and type each command line below one by one:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install syslinux
mount | grep cdrom
```

The last command above tells you to which device your bootable USB is on.

Important! replace **`<device>`** in the command below in the terminal with the device in the output of the last command above. Which will be something like `/dev/sdb1`

```
syslinux <device>
```

For a more detailed version of this answer see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746412/623554).

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me: I couldn't go to live but had to use start up disk creator on a Ubuntu 16 machine to create a start up disk for Ubuntu 16 itself.